# Do the Casimir operators for $su(3)$ algebra of particle physics carry any physical meaning?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory, invariants

For the $su(2) $ algebra of angular momentum, the eigenvalues of the Casimir operator, $\hat{J^2}$, represents the square of the total angular momentum of a system. The $su(3)$ algebra has rank 2 and therefore, it has two Casimir operators given by
$$
\hat{C}_1=\hat{T}_i \hat{T}_i, \quad \hat{C}_2 =d_{ijk}\hat{T}_i\hat{T}_j\hat{T}_k,
$$
where $T_i$'s are the generator and the sum over the repeated indices is implied. The group $SU(3)$ arises in particle physics, in the context of strong interactions and also in approximate flavor $SU(3)$ symmetry. Other than characterizing different multiplets, do the eigenvalues of $\hat{C}_1$ and $\hat{C}_2$ have any physical meaning? Are they measurable like $\hat{J^2}$ is?

Comment: Do anomaly coefficients carry physical meaning? How did you measure the su(2) Casimir?

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4742393/362193).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As group invariants, they serve to provide interaction terms in SU(3)-symmetric hamiltonians. SU(3) is also the symmetry group of [3-d quantum oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Symmetry_group_of_the_3D_oscillator_Hamiltonian_operator), and the quadratic Casimir is, of course, the [quadrupole-quadrupole interaction term](https://doi.org/10.1016/0029-5582(61)90253-X).

I copy the basic formulas from WP above, specifying their eigenvalues for the arbitrary irrep $D(p,q)$ (with *p* "quarks" and *q* "antiquarks"), of dimension $d(p,q)=\frac{1}{2}(p+1)(q+1)(p+q+2)$,
$$ {C}_1 = (p^2+q^2+3p+3q+pq)/3 \\
  {C}_2 =(p-q)(3+p+2q)(3+q+2p)/18 . $$
Note the first is symmetric in *p,q* interchange, and the second one antisymmetric. The latter is the triangle anomaly coefficient of QFT, and visibly vanishes for real, *p=q*, irreps!